# $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {\frac{1}{x}\left( f(x)+f(\frac{x}{2})+\cdots+f(\frac{x}{n})\right)}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

> let $f$ be a differentiable function at $x = 0$ and $f(0) = 0.$ For
> each $n\in N$, calculate the following limit: $I = \lim_{x \rightarrow
> > 0} {\frac{1}{x}\left( f(x)+f(\frac{x}{2})+\cdots+f(\frac{x}{n})\right)}$

I know $f'(0)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(h)}{h}}$, so does $I=f'(0)\frac{n(n+1)}{2}?$

Comment: 1+1/2+...+1/n ≠ n(n+1)/2

Answer (score 4):

Taking limits for individual terms and adding them up we see that the limit is $f'(0)[1+\frac 1  2+\frac  1n+\cdots+\frac  1n]$.

Comment: So my answer right $I=f'(0)\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: @tompi2394 How does summing an harmonic progression give you $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$? . The answer is just $f'(0)H_{n}$. $H_{n}$ is nth harmonic number

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron, Oh, Thank you, my bad!